# How to identify a coiled coil from the amino acid sequence?

Tags: protein-structure

I was wondering, when we have an amino acid sequence, is it enough to check whether the positions a-d correspond to hydrophobic amino acids in order to say whether it can form a coiled coil structure? Or would we need to make sure the other positions are not hydrophobic too?

All help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The heptad repeat, denoted [abcdefg]<sub>n</sub>, typically has hydrophobic residues at **a** and **d**, and polar/charged residues at **e** and **g**.

From [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2567808/).

There is a prediction tool with useful images [here](http://www.syntbio.net/bCIPA/).